# I WANT TO ASK A QUESTIONS ON ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have 5 rows with value as

```
1 121/2808B|:6081
2 OD308B|:6081_1:
3 008312100001200|:6081_1
4 MY NAME IS ANTHONY GONSAVLES|:
5 000300000010961 PIYUSH BARIA KIRALIK ASK|:



I want to display value AS 
1 121/2808B
2 OD308B
3 008312100001200
4 MY NAME IS ANTHONY GONSAVLES
5 000300000010961 PIYUSH BARIA KIRALIK ASK
```

WITHOUT USING REGEXP_SUBSTR

Comment: You need to look at the Oracle function `INSTR()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - using `instr()` and `substr()`

```
select substr(valuefield,1,instr(valuefield,'|:')-1) from tablename
```